# Is Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http required to get info for uploaded file

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm testing file upload with `Zend_Form_Element_File`. My form has this file element

```
    $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
    $file->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH);
    $this->addElement($file);
```

In the action, I've seen examples that just use `->receive()` to save the file

```
if($isPost()){
  if($formIsValid()){
     $form->file->receive(); 
  }
}
```

Other examples use `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http()` especially when trying to get file info. There's still `receive()` but it's on the http_adapter that they define in the action.

```
if($isPost()){
  if($formIsValid()){
     $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
     $upload->receive();
     $name = $upload->getFileName('file');
  }
}
```

My question: can I use `$form->file->receive()` like the first example and still get file details. I tried doing `$thefile = $form->file->receive();` but $thefile turned out to be a boolean.

I basically want to use `$form->file->receive()` without needing to define the `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` in the action. Is it possible or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get detailed info in your action as follows:

```
            $fileElem = $photosForm->getElement('file');
            $adapter = $fileElem->getTransferAdapter();
            var_dump($adapter->getFileInfo());
```